# How Sum with SQL server RollUP|SQL CUBE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Many Thanks for having to take your time to give some suggestions/help.
I have below data and I would like to calculate the total/sum across all the column group by year using SQL Server 2012. Below data is the score for four countries for different games, I would like to get the total score for all the countries together (4 distinct) group by year.

```
SELECT 
,Country    
,SUM(Football)    AS Football
,SUM(Basket)      AS Basket
,SUM(Ball)        AS Ball
,SUM(Volleyball)  Volleyball    
,Year 
From CountryScore

GROUP BY 
 GROUP BY SETS(Year,())
```

**Sample Data**

[image: Raw Data]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Answear]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `SUM` with add to your expect addition number columns.

```
CREATE TABLE CountryScore(
   year int,
   Football int,
   Basket int,
  Volleyball int
); 

INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (1996,4,6,7);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (1996,4,6,7);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (1996,6,7,7);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (1996,6,7,7);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (2000,7,4,8);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (2000,7,6,5);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (2000,6,6,6);
INSERT INTO CountryScore VALUES (2000,6,8,8);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
     [Year]    
    ,SUM(Football + Basket  + Volleyball) AS 'Total Score'
From CountryScore
GROUP BY 
     [Year]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c593/2/0)**:

```
| Year | Total Score |
|------|-------------|
| 1996 |          74 |
| 2000 |          77 |
```

If your value column possible be `NULL`, you can add `ISNULL` function to prevent it and set `NULL` to 0.

```
SELECT 
     [Year]    
    ,SUM(ISNULL(Football,0) + ISNULL(Basket,0)  + ISNULL(Volleyball,0)) AS 'Total Score'
From CountryScore
GROUP BY 
     [Year]
```

Comment: @SQLfun No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want play wise then you can use the below query

SELECT year,sum(Football)Football,sum(Basket)Basket,sum(Volleyball) Volleyball
From #CountryScore
group by grouping sets(year,())

Thanks
Sasi